# DCGAN: How to nearest neighbor on the training set in sense of compressed sensing?

Tags: tensorflow, autoencoders, gan

I want to find the nearest neighbor of the output compared to the training set based on this framework: https://github.com/carpedm20/DCGAN-tensorflow

(I asked already generally in this post: [Generative Adversarial Network: How to find the most similar image to the output within the training samples?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/311771/generative-adversarial-network-how-to-find-the-most-similar-image-to-the-output) with the answer:
"The best approach is probably to find nearest neighbors in a compressed representation space such as the latent code vector of a convolutional autoencoder.")

Now, I want to know, how to do that practical based on the DCGAN (see GitHub).

Has somebody an idea how to find the nearest neighbors? Where can I find a compressed representation space such as the latent code vector?

Comment: Did you get this done? If yes can you share the experience?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it done.